# Fetch data from Excel and append two or more values in a key of a JSON object using java

Tags: java, json, apache-poi

My requirement is to fetch data from excel sheet and convert the data into a nested json file using java.
Not just to create a key, value type of json rather a complex and dynamic one which **computes** based on the data entered into the excel.

[image]

the above data from the attached excel should be converted into below json.

```
{
    "Summary": {
        "Deposit": [
            "Contribution amt",
            "Withdrawal amt"
        ],
        "AXA Admin": [
            "Restrict Code",
            "User area"
        ]
    },
    "Coverage": {
        "Benefit Details": [
            "GMDB code",
            "Adjusted GMDB"
        ]
    }   
}
```

I tried this,

```
public static JsonObject getExcelDataAsJsonObject(String excelPath) throws Exception {

        File excelFile = new File(excelPath);
        JsonObject sheetsJsonObject = new JsonObject();
        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);

        JsonArray sheetArray = new JsonArray();
        ArrayList<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> sheetIterator = sheet.iterator();

        while (sheetIterator.hasNext()) {

            Row currentRow = sheetIterator.next();
            JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();

            // store column names
            for (int k = 0; k < currentRow.getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); k++)
                columnNames.add(currentRow.getCell(k).getStringCellValue());
            
            if (currentRow.getRowNum() != 0) {
                for (int j = 0; j < columnNames.size(); j++) {
                    if (currentRow.getCell(j) != null) {
                        if (currentRow.getCell(j).getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING)
                            jsonObject.addProperty(columnNames.get(j), currentRow.getCell(j).getStringCellValue());
                        else if (currentRow.getCell(j).getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC)
                            jsonObject.addProperty(columnNames.get(j), currentRow.getCell(j).getNumericCellValue());
                        else if (currentRow.getCell(j).getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.BOOLEAN)
                            jsonObject.addProperty(columnNames.get(j), currentRow.getCell(j).getBooleanCellValue());
                        else if (currentRow.getCell(j).getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.BLANK)
                            continue;
                        // jsonObject.addProperty(columnNames.get(j), "");

                    } else
                        continue;
                    // jsonObject.addProperty(columnNames.get(j), "");
                }

                sheetArray.add(jsonObject);

            }
        }

        sheetsJsonObject.add(workbook.getSheetName(0), sheetArray);
        return sheetsJsonObject;

    }
```

The above code is taking 1st Row as keys and the rows below them as values and it iterates till the last row of data.

It printed this in the console,

```
{"Sheet1":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{"Summary":"Coverage"},{},{},{}]}
```

Comment: "The above code is taking 1st Row as keys and the rows below them as values and it iterates till the last row of data.":  But that is not what is stored in your Excel sheet. So the need is to progam other code which considers how your Excel sheet stores data.

Comment: @AxelRichter Can you please help me with the logic to be used as I'm new to jsonObject.

Answer (score 1):

At first the problem is about how to read data which are stored that way in the Excel sheet. This data storage has nothing to do with how spreadsheet data normally are stored in a sheet. It looks as if someone tried mimic the JSON in the sheet. That's unusual, but so be it.

Sheets are stored row by row. And in your case each row may have one cell stored with following meaning:

- If first cell in row, then this is the key of the level 1 object.
- If second cell in row, then this is the key of the level 2 object.
- If third cell in row, then this is a item of the level 3 array.
- The level 1 object maps a list of n level 2 objects to the key.
- The level 2 object maps a list of n level 3 arrays to the key.
- The level 3 array contais n array items each.

Knowing this, the simplest way to produce JSON from this will be using a StringBuilder to append the found keys and/or array items delimeted with opening and closing tags. To open an object, "{" gets used. To open an array, "[" gets used. To close an object, when another follows, "}," gets used. To close an array, when another follows, "]," gets used. To close an object, when no other follows, "}" gets used. To close an array, when no other follows, "]" gets used. Array items are opened with no tag and closed using "," when another follows and using no tag, when no other folows.

The following code implements that logic. It produces a JSON text.

To validate whether that JSON is valid, it uses [org.json.JSONObject](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) to construct a `JSONObject` from that text.

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.json.JSONObject;

class ReadExcelToJSON {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("./ExcelExample.xlsx"));
  DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter(new java.util.Locale("en", "US"));
  // from 5.2.0 on the DataFormatter can set to use cached values for formula cells
  dataFormatter.setUseCachedValuesForFormulaCells(true);
  
  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  Cell cell;
  String cellValue;
  
  int firstRowNum = sheet.getFirstRowNum();
  short firstCellNum = sheet.getRow(firstRowNum).getFirstCellNum();

  StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  boolean level1Open = false;
  boolean level2Open = false;
  boolean level3Open = false;
  
  stringBuilder.append("{\n");
  for (Row row : sheet) {
   cell = row.getCell(firstCellNum + 0);
   cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
   if (!"".equals(cellValue)) { //level 1 key found
    // if previous levels are open, close them
    if (level3Open) {
     stringBuilder.append("\n");
     level3Open = false;
    }    
    if (level2Open) {
     stringBuilder.append("  ]\n");
     level2Open = false;
    }
    // if same level is open, close it followed by comma, because a new one get opened now  
    if (level1Open) {
     stringBuilder.append(" },\n");
     level1Open = false;
    }    
    stringBuilder.append(" \"" + cellValue + "\": {\n");
    level1Open = true;
   } else {
    cell = row.getCell(firstCellNum + 1);
    cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
    if (!"".equals(cellValue)) { //level 2 key found
     // if previous levels are open, close them
     if (level3Open) {
      stringBuilder.append("\n");
      level3Open = false;
     }
     // if same level is open, close it followed by comma, because a new one get opened now      
     if (level2Open) {
      stringBuilder.append("  ],\n");
      level2Open = false;
     }   
     stringBuilder.append("  \"" + cellValue + "\": [\n");
     level2Open = true;
    } else {
     cell = row.getCell(firstCellNum + 2);
     cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
     if (!"".equals(cellValue)) { //level 3 array item found
      if (level3Open) {
       // if same level is open, close it followed by comma, because a new one get opened now
       stringBuilder.append(",\n");
       level3Open = false;
      }  
      stringBuilder.append("   \"" + cellValue + "\"");
      level3Open = true;
     } else {
      // empty row, do nothing
     }     
    }      
   }
  }
  // if previous levels are open, close them
  if (level3Open) {
   stringBuilder.append("\n");
   level3Open = false;
  }  
  if (level2Open) {
   stringBuilder.append("  ]\n");
   level2Open = false;
  }  
  if (level1Open) {
   stringBuilder.append(" }\n");
   level1Open = false;
  }  
  stringBuilder.append("}\n");
 
  String jsonText = stringBuilder.toString();
  System.out.println(jsonText);
  
  JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(jsonText);
  System.out.println(jsonObject.toString(1));

  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

---

Following is the above approach coded more dynamic.

It uses the used range of the sheet from first row to last column. Values in last column are array items. All previous columns contain key values for objects, either objects or arrays, mapping following column values to that key.

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.json.JSONObject;

class ReadExcelToJSONmultipleLevels {
    
 static CellRangeAddress getUsedRange(Sheet sheet) {
  int firstRow = sheet.getFirstRowNum();
  if (firstRow == -1) return null;
  int lastRow = sheet.getLastRowNum();
  if (lastRow == -1) return null;
  int firstCol = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
  int lastCol = -1;
  for (int r = firstRow; r <= lastRow; r++) {
   Row row = sheet.getRow(r);
   if (row != null) {
    int thisRowFirstCol = row.getFirstCellNum();
    int thisRowLastCol = row.getLastCellNum()-1; // see API doc Row.getLastCellNum : Gets the index of the last cell contained in this row PLUS ONE.
    if (thisRowFirstCol < firstCol) firstCol = thisRowFirstCol;
    if (thisRowLastCol > lastCol) lastCol = thisRowLastCol;
   }   
  }
  if (firstCol == Integer.MAX_VALUE) return null;
  if (lastCol == -1) return null;
  return new CellRangeAddress(firstRow, lastRow, firstCol, lastCol);
 }  

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("./ExcelExample.xlsx"));
  DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter(new java.util.Locale("en", "US"));
  // from 5.2.0 on the DataFormatter can set to use cached values for formula cells
  dataFormatter.setUseCachedValuesForFormulaCells(true);
  
  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  Cell cell;
  String cellValue;

  CellRangeAddress usedRange = getUsedRange(sheet);
  
  System.out.println(usedRange); 
  
  int firstRowNum = usedRange.getFirstRow();
  int firstCellNum = usedRange.getFirstColumn();
  
  int levelCount =  usedRange.getLastColumn() - usedRange.getFirstColumn() + 1;
  
  if (levelCount < 2) return;

  StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  
  boolean[] isLevelOpen = new boolean[levelCount];
  for (int i = 0; i < levelCount; i++) isLevelOpen[i] = false;
  
  stringBuilder.append("{\n");
    
  for (Row row : sheet) {
   for (int level = 0; level < levelCount; level++) {
    cell = row.getCell(firstCellNum + level);
    cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
    if (!"".equals(cellValue)) { //level found
     // if previous levels are open, close them
     for (int i = levelCount-1; i >= level; i--) {
      if (isLevelOpen[i] && i != level) {
       if (i==levelCount-1) stringBuilder.append("\n"); //last level
       else if (i==levelCount-2) stringBuilder.append("]\n"); //penultimate level
       else stringBuilder.append("}\n"); //other previous levels
       isLevelOpen[i] = false;
      }
      // if same level is open, close it followed by comma, because a new one get opened now  
      if (isLevelOpen[i] && i == level) {
       if (i==levelCount-1) stringBuilder.append(",\n"); //last level
       else if (i==levelCount-2) stringBuilder.append("],\n"); //penultimate level
       else stringBuilder.append("},\n"); //other previous levels
       isLevelOpen[i] = false;
      }
     }    

     String startTag = "";
     if (level == levelCount-1) startTag = "";
     else if (level == levelCount-2) startTag = ": [\n";
     else startTag = ": {\n";
     stringBuilder.append(" \"" + cellValue + "\"" + startTag);
     isLevelOpen[level] = true;
    }
   }
  }
  
  // if previous levels are open, close them
  for (int i = levelCount-1; i >= 0; i--) {
   String endTag = "";
   if (i == levelCount-1) endTag = "\n";
   else if (i == levelCount-2) endTag = "]\n";
   else endTag = "}\n";
   if (isLevelOpen[i]) {
    stringBuilder.append(endTag);
    isLevelOpen[i] = false;
   }  
  }
  
  stringBuilder.append("}\n");
 
  String jsonText = stringBuilder.toString();
  System.out.println(jsonText);
  
  JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(jsonText);
  System.out.println(jsonObject.toString(1));

  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.  This is working dynamically towards row wise whereas it is not dynamically fetching after 3rd column. If possible can you please make it dynamic on both row and column wise

Comment: @Shyam Sundar V: Not possible as an entry in 4th column is not defined. What kind of JSON element should an entry in the 4th column be stored in?

Comment: The utmost child element should be enclosed in square brackets whereas the parent and the ancestors should be enclosed in curly braces. For example if the child elements are located in 8th column it should be enclosed in square brackets and the parent and ancestors should be enclosed in curly braces.

Comment: @Shyam Sundar V: See supplement to my answer.